# Alexa Skill - Unable to get data from Intent

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I am trying to implement an Alexa Skill with Multi Turn method and a Node.js back end.

```js
alexaApp.intent("findFact", {
    "dialog": {
      type: "delegate"
    },
  },
  function(request, response) {
    console.log("In Fact intent");
  
    var test = this.event.request.intent.slots.testtwo.value;
  
   // console.log(request.dialogState);
    console.log("test fact : " + test);
      response.say(get_fact());
    }
);
```

Iam not able to get the value within the testtwo slot.

The console displays 'Unhandled exception: Cannot read property 'request' of undefined.'
Any idea why ?

Thanks !

---

ANSWER IS :
var test = request.data.request.intent.slots.testtwo.value;

Comment: Why are you doing `this.event.request...` when request is passed in?  Shouldn't you just use `request.intent.slots.testtwo.value` directly?

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I have tested with just "test = request.intent.slots.testtwo.value" it gave me "Unhandled exception: Cannot read property 'slots' of undefined."

Comment: Hi Jerry, thanks for your help ! the answer was to add replace "this.event" by "request.data"